# How to set the ZK combo box width

Tags: css, grails, combobox, zk

I am newbie to ZK framework, I am using **ZK plugin with Grails**.The **combobox width is too large**, Its occupying the entire div width, and its being generated dynamically. The code is below:

```
<div id="i5CQc5-pp" class="z-combobox-popup  z-combobox-open z-combobox-shadow" style="z-index: 1800; width: 1747px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 219px; left: 139px;" tabindex="-1">
    <ul id="i5CQc5-cave" class="z-combobox-content" style="height: auto; width: 100%;">
        <li id="i5CQd5" class="z-comboitem"><span class="z-comboitem-image"></span><span class="z-comboitem-text">pass</span></li>
        <li id="i5CQe5" class="z-comboitem"><span class="z-comboitem-image"></span><span class="z-comboitem-text">fail</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the css below:

```
element.style {
    z-index: 1800;
    width: 1747px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 219px;
    left: 139px;
}

.z-combobox-popup, .z-combobox-popup {
    font-size: 917em;
}

.z-combobox-popup, .z-combobox-popup {
    font-size: 917em;
}

.z-combobox-shadow, .z-bandbox-shadow, .z-datebox-shadow {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.z-combobox-popup {
    overflow: auto;
}

.z-combobox-popup, .z-bandbox-popup, .z-datebox-popup, .z-timebox-popup {
    font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How to set the width so that minimum width will be same as Combobox

OR

How to set the width so that min width will be same as combobox and

Comment: Is that the generated code? I have no experience with grails but with normal zul files I do.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the zul file generated by the ZK Grails plugin, modify width to suit your needs. No need to use CSS.

[ZK Combobox reference](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Input/Combobox)